Identify if an environment variable is unset
I'm trying to write an ansible playbook to install my application. I'm trying to detect that an environment variable is unset. I know I can use the lookup plugin to find an environment variable like this: lookup('env', 'FOO').
My problem is that if the environment variable is not set, lookup returns a blank string. However if the environment variable is set, and happens to be a blank string, I won't be able to tell if the environment variable is actually set to "" or entirely unset.
# my task:
- name:
  when: lookup('env', 'FOO') == ''
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "FOO is unset!"

This task will print the debug message if FOO is unset, but also if FOO is actually a blank string.
According to the documentation, lookup supports a default parameter. Also according to the documentation, setting default=Undefined or default=undef() will cause the playbook to fail -- which is true, it throws a templating error.
Since this is basically Python under the covers, I tried setting default=None and checking like that:
- name:
  when: lookup('env', 'FOO', default=None) is None
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    msg: "FOO is unset!"

However that returned a templating error because apparently Jinja doesn't understand None.
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The conditional check 'lookup('env', 'FOO', default=None) is None' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: Could not load \"None\": 'None'.  ..."
}

How do I go about identifying that an environment variable is actually undefined/unset? (Not a blank string. A blank string is allowed, but it's set in that case. This variable is literally allowed to be set to anything; I just want to detect when it's not.)

The jinja value for None is none, but that won't help you; given:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          {{ lookup('env', 'TESTVAR', default=none) }}

When TESTVAR is unset, the we get:
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": ""
}

I think the syntax of the lookup() function isn't terribly useful in this case. I think your best option to check for an unset environment variable is to ask the shell, something like this:
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - register: res
      failed_when: false
      changed_when: res.rc != 0
      shell: |
        [ -z ${TESTVAR+x} ] && exit 1 || exit 0

    - when: res is changed
      debug:
        msg: "TESTVAR is unset"

When TESTVAR is unset, we get:
TASK [shell] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "TESTVAR is unset"
}

When TESTVAR is set -- even to an empty string -- we get:
TASK [shell] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]


The module setup subset env provides you with the dictionary ansible_env. See gather_subset
    - setup:
        gather_subset: env

    - debug:
        var: ansible_env

gives, for example, if you set FOO=bar
  ansible_env:
    BROWSER: /usr/bin/chromium-browser
    CLUTTER_BACKEND: x11
    COLORTERM: truecolor
    DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS: unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
    DEBUGINFOD_URLS: 'https://debuginfod.ubuntu.com '
    DESKTOP_SESSION: xubuntu
    DISPLAY: :0.0
    EDITOR: emacs
    FOO: bar
    ...

Declare the variable to make the code cleaner. (You can use a literal if you want to.)
  my_env_var: FOO

You can test it first
    - assert:
        that: my_env_var in ansible_env

This will fail if FOO is missing, otherwise display the value
    - debug:
        var: ansible_env[my_env_var]

gives
  ansible_env[my_env_var]: bar

If FOO is not set you'll see
  ansible_env[my_env_var]: None

As a result, you can't set the string None as a valid value. Proceed if you can live with this limitation.
You have to test None to find out whether FOO is set or not
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_env_var }} is unset!"
      when: ansible_env[my_env_var] == 'None'

Notes:

lookup works only on the Ansible controller.
See Setting the remote environment



Test all three options in the playbook below:
  environment:
    FOO: bar

  environment:
    FOO:

  environment:
    # FOO: bar

Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost
  environment:
    FOO: bar

  vars:

    my_env_var: FOO

  tasks:

    - setup:
        gather_subset: env

    - debug:
        var: ansible_env

    - assert:
        that: my_env_var in ansible_env

    - debug:
        var: ansible_env[my_env_var]
    - debug:
        var: ansible_env[my_env_var] | type_debug

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_env_var }} is unset!"
      when: ansible_env[my_env_var] == 'None'


